# how can I pull from another branch without leaving the current one?

Tags: git

I find myself doing this repeatedly.

I'm in branch `dev`.

```
git checkout master
git pull upstream master
git checkout dev
git rebase master
```

Is there a way I can do a pull as if I were in `master`, without having to leave `dev`?

Comment: `git pull` essentially is `git fetch ...` + `git merge`

Comment: Do you want to be able to update another branch while not being on that branch?  Is that all this is?  (Note that I'm not saying or stating or insinuating in any way that this is *easy*, I just want to be clear.)

Comment: I want master always to be the exact copy of upstream/master and based on that rebase dev

Answer (score 1):

... so

```
git checkout dev
git fetch upstream
git merge upstream/master
```

Alternatively, as @Makoto suggests, if you want to keep your branch history "linear", you may replace `git merge upstream/master` with `git rebase upstream/master`. Also `git rebase` has a nice `-i` option which allows you to select which commits you wish to rebase and in which order

Comment: I'm not sure this really conveys what the user wants.

Comment: I assume that he/she wants to merge `dev` with the latest changes from upstream's `master`

Comment: I don't see them wanting to merge master into their branch.  I see them wanting to move their branch to the tip of whatever the remote's master commit is and replaying their work on top of that.

Comment: actually i want to do both

Comment: sorry, bu i don't see the benefit of your command, it is exactly 4 commands (you ommited `git checkout dev` as i need to endup in `dev`)

Comment: these commands (`git fetch upstream` + {`git merge upstream/master` | `git rebase upstream/master`}) bring fresh changes from upstream's `master` branch into your `dev`. Or may be you asked for something different? Please clarify.